# List<List<Integer>> to 2-D array conversion (int[][])

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, wrapper

I want to convert `List<List<Integer>>` into the 2-D array in java. I am able to do that with the following code, but the problem my 2-d array uses primitive data type.

```
Integer[][] array = new Integer[resultList.size()][];
        for (i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> row = (ArrayList<Integer>) resultList.get(i);
            array[i] = row.toArray(new Integer[row.size()]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you want a `int[][]` rather than a `Integer[][]`. in which case I would go with:

```
int[][] result = resultList.stream()                                
       .map(l -> l.stream().mapToInt(e -> e).toArray()) 
       .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by iterating `List<List<Integer>>` and copying elements of `List<Integer>` into the corresponding rows of `int [][] array`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> list = List.of(List.of(10, 20), List.of(5, 15));
        int[][] array = new int[list.size()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            array[i] = new int[list.get(i).size()];
            for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size(); j++) {
                array[i][j] = list.get(i).get(j);
            }
        }

        // Display array[][]
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[10, 20], [5, 15]]
```